# EclipseLink JPA with N+1 @OneToMany and @OneToOne relationships with multilevel entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I have to fetch the details based on departmentId and below conditions. I am using **eclipseLink JPA** 2.4+

```
if IS_SUBJECT = 2 Teacher entity should join with Subject
if IS_SUBJECT = 1 Teacher entity should join with Lab
```

**when I fetch with departmentId values should map into Department and Teacher entities. JPA query as below.**

```
SELECT distinct f FROM Department f " +
    " join fetch f.teacherList fm" +
    " join fetch fm.subject fmi on (f.isSubject = 2 and fm.subjectId = fmi.subjectId) " +
    " join fetch fm.lab fmg on (f.isSubject = 1 and fm.labId = fmg.labId) " +
    " WHERE f.departmentId IN :departmentIdList".
```

**Entities as below:**

```
@Entity
public class Department{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Integer departmentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Teacher> teacherList;

    @Column(name="IS_SUBJECT")
    private isSubject;
}

@Entity
public class Teacher{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEACHER_ID")
    private Integer teacherId;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Integer departmentId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    private Integer subjectId;

    @Column(name = "LAB_ID")
    private Integer labId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    private Department department;

    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    private Subject subject;

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LAB_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Lab lab;

}

@Entity
public class Subject{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    private Integer subjectId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_NAME")
    private Integer subjectName;

}

@Entity
public class Lab{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LAB_ID")
    private Integer labId;

    @Column(name = "LAB_NAME")
    private Integer labName;

}
```

The generated query is taking long time to fetch from eclipse link JPA. Please help me on writing the query.

Comment: What is the SQL that is generated? You can get the SQL by enabling logging (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging ) I wasn't aware JPQL allowed nested fetch joins or that query filtering would work on a fetch join - they really shouldn't, and I suspect your attempts at optimizations at the various levels are causing duplicates and multiple queries. Why do you have BatchFetch on all your mappings if you intend to also specify fetch join?

Comment: @Chris : if I don't use the batch fetch it is querying the subject entity and lab entity separately for each record. It is generating 3 queries as below.
Query1:
SELECT DISTINCT t1.DEPARTMENT_ID,t1.IS_SUBJECT, t0.TEACHER_ID, t0.SUBJECT_ID, t0.LAB_ID  FROM Teacher t0, Department t1 WHERE ((t1.DEPARTMENT_ID IN (?)) AND (t0.DEPARTMENT_ID = t1.DEPARTMENT_ID))

Query 2:
SELECT SUBJECT_ID, SUBJECT_NAME FROM Subject WHERE (SUBJECT_ID = ?)

Query 3:
SELECT LAB_ID, LAB_NAME FROM Lab WHERE (LAB_ID = ?)

Comment: I'm not telling you to remove the batch fetch annotation - it can be a good one - only that it doesn't make any sense if you also use a fetch join on the very same relationship. Do you want all those rows brought back in a single query (fetch join) or in 3 queries (batch queries). All teachers have a lab and a subject that must be eagerly fetched based on your mappings, so you don't gain anything through the 'selective' fetch logic you are looking to add - JPA is required to full populate all teacher instances. Maybe if you made them lazy you'd gain something